# responsive operation in an Image Button using the percentage

Tags: android

please see the following code.How do I do responsive operation in an **Image Button** using the  percentage? I do not want create separate layout for one image! Can I use the  percentage way to  responsive operation in an **Image Button** to good show in different screens.

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/webView" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what do you mean.

Comment: Thank you. I want display an **ImageButton** in different screens.Is there a way for it in xml file. for example in 'html code' we use from  the percentage for responsive operation.  I want display an **ImageButton** in each screen well.I want the easiest way for an **ImageButton** to good show in each screen.